# How to restart a videosphere from the beginning before it stops in aframe?

Tags: aframe

I need to restart a videosphere from the beginning after paused it. Any ideas?

```
<a-assets>
  <video id="myVideo" src="myvideo.mp4"></video>
</a-assets>
<a-videosphere src="#myVideo"></a-videosphere>

document.querySelector('#myVideo').pause();
// Now how to restart?
```

I am not sure how to reset the videosphere.

Comment: The [video-controls](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-controls) component may the place to start. If you want to control the video from JS, you can look at its code for help. 

P.S. The downvotes are related to [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which basically says to include what you've tried, any errors you encountered, and enough detail to show that you've spent some time trying already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/material.html#video-textures

> To control the video playback such as pausing or seeking, we can use the video element to control media playback. For example:

```
var videoEl = document.querySelector('#my-video');
videoEl.currentTime = 122;  // Seek to 122 seconds.
videoEl.pause();
```

> This doesn’t work as well if you are passing an inline URL, in which case a video element will be created internally. To get a handle on the video element, we should define one in .